# Why Picasso is not using imageView.getContext()?

Tags: android, android-context, picasso

Stupid question:

if context can be obtained from imageView itself, why bother passing it explicitly?
what would be wrong if Picasso did something like this:

```
Picasso.load(url).into(imageView);
```

instead of

```
Picasso.with(context).load(url).into(imageView);
```

?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A context is used to initialize the disk cache, load local resources, and communicate with content providers and `into` isn't always the action method that's invoked. There's also `get()` and `fetch()`.

Comment: so it is not a problem if I do Picasso.with(imageView.getContext()).load(url).into(imageView)?

Comment: Not at all! We also ensure that we call `getApplicationContext()` on any `Context` you supply to not hold any strong references to views or activities.

Answer (score -1):

```
ImageView imageView=(ImageView)header.findViewById(R.id.userImage);
Picasso.with(imageView.getContext()).load("https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/#HASH#?s=64&d=mm&r=g").into(imageView);
```

Comment: It's not a "How" question, it's a "Why" question